# JQuery form serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

I'm having issues using `.serialize()` on the following form:

```
        <form id="cfgedit">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="row center-align">
                    <div class="col s12 m4 input-field"><input type="text" id="bpid" name="bpid" value="" /><label for="bpid">Business Partner</label></div>
                    <div class="col s12 m4 input-field"><input type="text" id="serviceid" name="serviceid" value="" /><label for="serviceid">Service ID</label></div>
                    <div class="col s12 m4 input-field"><input type="text" id="servicetype" name="servicetype" value="" /><label for="servicetype">Service Type</label></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row teal lighten-5">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <textarea id="smstext" name="smstext" class="materialize-textarea flow-text" length="160"></textarea>
                        <label for="smstext">SMS Text</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m6 input-field right-align"><input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="" /><label for="url">Url destinazione</label></div>
                    <div class="col s12 m6"><strong>Validit&agrave;:</strong><br />
                        <input type="number" name="validityD" min="0" value="1"> d
                        <input type="number" name="validityH" min="0" max="23" value="0"> h
                        <input type="number" name="validityM" min="0" max="59" value="0"> m
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a class="btn btn-large waves-effect red" href="/admin">Cancel</a>
                <a class="waves-effect btn-large right" id="persist">Save</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I'm using `$.ajax` to post the form to my back-end, bound to #persist button click.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/config/add",
    data: $("#cfgedit").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
            // display ok
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
            // display not ok
    }
});
```

Now the issue I'm facing is with the `$.ajax` data. Because using Chrome's console and typing `$("#cfgedit").serialize();` I do get the correct form serialization:

```
"bpid=TEST_BP&serviceid=TEST_SID&servicetype=TEST_ST&smstext=SMS_TEXT&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.url&validityD=1&validityH=2&validityM=3"
```

But if I send the form, that same serialize returns only

```
"smstext=SMS_TEXT"
```

The fields I'm expecting in output all have name attribute set.

Comment: And what you get on server side?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I was just getting smstext, but I've just posted the answer myself. I didn't know serialize is not serializing disabled inputs. my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved: I was disabling form inputs to don't let user modify stuff while performing the ajax request:

```
$("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

saving values before disabling the inputs solved the problem.

```
var values = $("#cfgedit").serialize();
```

.serialize() is not serializing disabled fields.